# Why can't I add a string to a structure?

Tags: c, string, struct

So I'm trying to create a program that reads data into a file. But before that I need to store the data into a struct. How do I store a string in a struct?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 100

int count;

struct cg {
    float price;
    char singer, song;
    int release;
} hold[100];

int main() {
    while (1) {
        printf("Name of band of Singer: ");
        scanf_s("%s,", &hold[count].singer);

        printf("Name of Song: ");
        scanf_s("%c", &hold[count].song);

        printf("Price: ");
        scanf_s("%f", &hold[count].price);

        printf("Year of Release: ");
        scanf_s("%d", &hold[count].release);

        count++;
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of `char singer, song;` use `char singer[100], song[200];` for a singer of up to 99 characters and a song of up to 199 characters.

Comment: Or consider using pointers to dynamically allocated character arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the question here is about storing strings in a `struct`, here is a bare-bones solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX 100

int count;
struct cg {
    float price;
    char singer[20], song[20];
    int release;
}hold[100];

int main() {
        printf("Name of band of Singer: ");
        fgets(hold[0].singer, 20, stdin);
        printf("Singer: %s\n", hold[0].singer);
}
```

This program just demonstrates storing a string in a struct. Here, `20` is the maximum number of characters (including the terminating `NUL`) you can store in `singer` or `song`. Optionally, you could also allocate memory dynamically using `malloc()` for the strings to store.

Please note that several other problems with your program. For e.g. your loop never ends and a `}` is missing.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. The original code was much longer and I only copied the section I needed help with. For the other variables I can just use scanf right?

Comment: Avoid mixing fgets and scanf.  Also recall that fgets includes the newline at the end.